# Convert a JavaScript variable to a PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm learning HTML JS CSS and PHP and I have a big problem.

The `$input` variable in `getPosForLieferschein()` should be the user input, but I found no way to convert JS variables to PHP. The user should write a contract number into the input field and the contract positions - getPosForLieferschein() - show up in the table below. The page should **not** be reloaded just in case that no other way works. I know the code is terrible!

Head:

```
<?php include 'connection_manager.php'; $tags = getLieferscheine();?>
<script type="text/javascript">

var availableTags = "<?php echo $tags;?>"

$(function () {
    var values = availableTags.split(",");
    $('.select').autocomplete({
        source: values
    });
});

function generate() {
    var eingabe = document.getElementById('input').value;
    var position = "<?php $positionen = getPosForLieferschein($input); echo $positionen; ?>";
    var arr = position.split(','), contract = arr[0], pos = arr[1], article = arr[2], name = arr[3], amount = arr[4], unit = arr[5];
    var table = document.getElementById("table1body");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell6 = row.insertCell(2);
    var i = 60;
    var a = document.getElementById("input");
    if ((a.value == eingabe)) {
        while (i > 0) {
            cell1.innerHTML = contract;
            cell2.innerHTML = pos;
            cell3.innerHTML = unit;
            cell4.innerHTML = amount;
            cell5.innerHTML = name;
            cell6.innerHTML = article;
            i = i - 60;
        }
    }
    else {
        swal({
            title: "Fehler!",
            text: "Bitte geben Sie eine gültige Auftragsnummer ein!",
            type: "error",
            confirmButtonText: "Ok",
            confirmButtonColor: "#FF0000"
        });
    }
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#details").click(function () {
        $("#uebertragen").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#details").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    })
    $("#uebertragen").click(function () {
        $("#details").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#uebertragen").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    })
})

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#uebertragen").click(function () {
        $("td").remove()
    })
})
</script>
```

Body:

```
<body>
<center>
<img style="position:relative;left:25px;" src="quehenberger.jpg" height="50px" width="240px" alt="quehenberger logo" align="left"/>
<img style="position:relative;right:25px;" src="bilton.png" height="50px" width="300px" alt="bilton logo" align="right"/>
<h1><b>QLog Eingabe</b></h1>
<hr/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
           <form action="" method="get">
            <input id="input" type="text" style="width:50%;position:relative;left:14em;" value="" class="select form-control col-xs-1" Placeholder="Auftragsnummer"/>
            <button style="position:relative;left:18em;" id="details" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-success" onclick="generate();">Pr&uuml;fen</button>
           </form>
    </div>
    </p>
    <button style="width:100px;position:relative;left:58.65em;" id="uebertragen" disabled="disabled" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-danger">&Uuml;bertragen</button>
</div>
<table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Auftragsnummer</th>
            <th>Positions Nummer</th>
            <th>Artikel Nummer</th>
            <th>Artikel Bezeichnung</th>
            <th>Artikel Menge</th>
            <th>Einheit</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="table1body">
        </tbody>
</table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You (or anyone else for that matter) will never get PHP to run inside Javascript.  PHP executes on the SERVER, then outputs HTML to the BROWSER, where Javascript takes over.

Comment: Yeah i know it is hard to work with php and js together but i have no other option to do that

Comment: Its not hard to work with them both together, but you need to understand that the way you have coded them will never ever ever ever work.

Comment: Yes but i get the positions for the table from a php file and i don't know how to convert them to js

Comment: getPosForLieferschein() is a string i got from connection_manager.php and it depends on the contract number wich positions should be shown in the table

Comment: if what you mean in comments is correct, then your question is very badly worded as it implies the opposite of what youre saying here. Im confused as to what youre trying to achieve.

Comment: The user writes a contract number into the input field. And every contract number has own positions. So the positions depends on the contract number written into the input field. I get the positions from getPosForLieferschein(). The $input variable should be the user input (contract number). So I just need the user input in the $input variable

Comment: It works when i write eg 46027 instead of $input, because thats a contract number.

Comment: What you really want to do is to use JS to send an AJAX request to the server (PHP) when the user updates an input file. The server will execute `getPosForLieferschein()` to get the _positions_ you need. When it has them, it will send a JSON object to the browser, where JS will insert them into the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final code! Thanks for help guys! :D`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var availableTags = "<?php echo $tags;?>"
    var currentTag = false;

    $(function(){
        var values = availableTags.split(",");
        $('.select').autocomplete({
            source: values,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                //$('#input').val()
                //console.log(ui.item.value);
                getAuftrag(ui.item.value);
            }
        });
    });

    function sendAuftrag() {
        if (currentTag !== false) {
            $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "save.php",
            data: {
                q : currentTag
                },
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#tableBody").html("");
                $("#uebertragen").attr("disabled", "disabled");

                swal({title: "Erfolg!",
                    text: "Auftragsnummer " + currentTag + " erfolgreich übermittelt!",
                    type: "success",
                    confirmButtonText: "Ok",
                    confirmButtonColor: "#FF0000"
                    });

                currentTag = false;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    function getAuftrag(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("tableBody").innerHTML = "";
            currentTag = false;
            return;
        }

        var values = availableTags.split(",");

        if (values.indexOf(str) === -1) {
            currentTag = false;
            swal({title: "Fehler!",
                text: "Bitte geben Sie eine gültige Auftragsnummer ein!",
                type: "error",
                confirmButtonText: "Ok",
                confirmButtonColor: "#FF0000"
            });
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: {
                    q : str
                    },
                dataType: "html",
                beforeSend: function(jqxhr) {
                    currentTag = str;
                    },
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#tableBody").html(data);

                    $("#uebertragen").removeAttr("disabled");
                    // console.log(data);
                    }
            });
        }
    }



    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#uebertragen").click(function(){
            $("#uebertragen").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        })
})
</script>`
```

HTML:

```
`<body>
<center>
<img style="position:relative;left:25px;" src="quehenberger.jpg" height="50px" width="240px" alt="quehenberger logo" align="left"/>
<img style="position:relative;right:25px;" src="bilton.png" height="50px" width="300px" alt="bilton logo" align="right"/>
<h1><b>QLog Eingabe</b></h1>
<hr/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
            <input id="input" style="width:50%;position:relative;left:14em;" class="select form-control col-xs-1" Placeholder="Auftragsnummer"/>

            <!-- <button style="position:relative;left:18em;" id="details" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-success" >Pr&uuml;fen</button> -->
            <button style="width:100px;position:relative;left:18em;" id="uebertragen" disabled="disabled" class="col-xs-1 btn btn-danger">&Uuml;bertragen</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="tableBody"><b></b></div>

<div style="background-color: #E6E6E6;height:40px;width:100%;" data-role="footer" data-tap-toggle="false" class="ics-footer">
    <p>Copyright IcoSense GmbH. All rights reserved.</p>
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>`
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just convert the variable. It is **not possible**. There are other options to make changes to the page without reloading:

1. You can make an ajax request each time the user input field has its content changed. Do all the calculations you need to do in the controller (server side) and just return the result and display it in the same page.
2. If you would use Yii2 framework, there would be another option. But this would require you to make some changes to the structure of your functions. In Yii2 you can write your JS in the view file and use values of PHP varibles. There is some info about that function [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html#registerJs()-detail).

As I understand, you are not using any framework, so I would suggest to use ajax requests and pass the calculated values back to the page (option 1).

Comment: Thanks for help! I'll try that! I keep telling you if it worked